# Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be elements in a boolean algebra and $a+c = a+b$ and $ab = ac$. Then prove that $b = c$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science, boolean-algebra

To prove it, I did the following:

We suppose two different values for $a$; $a = 0$ and $a \not= 0$

1. if $a=0$ then eliminating two $a$ form $a+c=a+b$ leads us to $b=c$
2. if $a \not= 0$ then from $ab=ac$ we have:

$ab-ac=0$ ------> $a(b-c)=0$ --- $a\not=0$ ---> $b-c=0$ ------> $b=c$

Is my proof correct and acceptable?

Comment: I don't believe $xy = 0$ and $x \neq 0$ implies $y=0$ in a general Boolean algebra.  (It's certainly not true in the power set of $A$ when $|A| > 1$)

Comment: The result is true for every distributive lattice, in particular, BA. But that second part of your proof is wrong, as pointed out in another comment.

Comment: You suddenly jump into using subtraction... to be clear you're using these operations to mean the idempotent meet-join operations or are you meaning the boolean ring operations addition and subtraction where $a+a=0$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yeah you are right. TY for you help.

Comment: @amrsa Got it TY.

Comment: @rschwieb I just used regular subtraction from math... But it was a dope move from me cause it's boolean algebra...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be acquainted with distributivity and absorption.
With those properties, if
$$a + c = a + b$$
and $$ab = ac,$$
then
\begin{align}
b
&= b(a+b)\\
&= b(a+c)\\
&= ab + bc\\
&= ac + bc\\
&= (a + b)c\\
&= (a + c)c\\
&= c.
\end{align}
(I'll leave it to you to identify which property is used where.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah it's obvious which property is used where. I got it completely :)